# Is it necessary to append Field-Value pairs in MongoDB?

Tags: json, database, mongodb, nosql

This is related to MongoDB. I have two documents defined in the same collection as follows. The data is related but that is spread across 2 documents. Will there be a problem in Querying a particular field from this collection or should we create a document and keep appending new field value pairs in addition to existing "Field:value" pairs similar to document #3

## 1

{
    "name":"David",
    "age":30,
    "team":"ManU"
}

## 2

{
    "gender":"Male",
    "profession":"FootballPlayer"
}

## 3

{
    "name":"David",
    "age":30,
    "team":"ManU",
    "gender":"Male",
    "profession":"FootballPlayer",
    "Country":"England"
}

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB was created with keeping this kind of use case in mind. In RDBMS we have different tables that are related to each other and store specific information in it. So if we have to get some information which is dependent on 2 or more tables then we need to use join.
In MongoDB, we store all the information which is possible to be stored together in a single document so that we can query collection on different criteria at once.

In your given example if you need to query on the basis of "age" is greater than 25 & "profession" is Football Player then it will be better if all the information is stored in a single document as we will get to know if a user qualifies criteria in single document read. If this information is stored in different documents then you will have to do some extra computation to verify if a user has passed the criteria in both the documents or not.

**TL;DR => While using MongoDB, it is always better to store as much relatable information to be stored in a single document.**